# Find the angle between the diagonals in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Find the missing angle, $\theta$, between the diagonals in a quadrilateral.
The angle $\angle ABC$ is right.
I can find any other angle, except the angles between the diagonals. Any hint of how to find $\theta$?

[image]

Comment: If you knew $\angle BDC$ then the problem would be easy, so I suppose you do **not** know how to "find any other angle". Which angles have you figured out?

Comment: I suppose this is what you need: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843269/all-relationships-between-angles-formed-by-drawing-diagonals-of-a-quadrilateral?rq=1

Comment: Hint: External angle bisectors of a triangle, and the internal angle bisector of the third vertex, intersect at the same point (excenter)

Comment: the hint posted by @ペガサスSeiya and StAKmod 's answer together complete the answer

Answer (score 5):

[image: Illustration]

The key observation is that $BD$ bisects $\measuredangle{ADC}$(I used a different naming of the vertices).

The hint to proving this: observe that if we draw perpendicular lines $BH$,$BI$,$BJ$ to $AD$,$AC$,$CD$, then $BA$ bisects $\measuredangle{HAI}$ and $BC$ bisects $\measuredangle{ICJ}.$

Answer (score 1):

There are many quadrilaterals with all integer angles.
For example this one. I doubt if there is always a "clever and simple" reasoning about the diagonal angle. Expressing the coordinates of C en D in terms of the angles and using the inproduct results -with use of a calculator- in the angles asked.
[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, and this is somewhat incorrect as well

Comment: The question was how to find the angle between the diagonals. My answer is: Use the  inproduct between AB and CD (both expressed in terms of these angles. But the resulting expression for the angle needs to be entered in a calculator to get the result. I expressed my belief that in the general case there is no shorter method.

Comment: There is a shorter method, even for a general case depending on if we have an important constraint to work with. As I said, this does not actually answer the question. At the very least I would say you should use the approach you suggest and find the answer, just some constructive criticism @PaulvdVeen

Comment: @Seiya. My apologies. 
By calculating the vector CD and applying the inner product of vector AB and CD I established an angle of 85 degrees.

Comment: $\theta=180-85=95$, not $85$ @PaulvdDeen

Comment: I made a small applet to play with. https://www.vandeveen.nl/Quadrilaterals.html

Comment: @PaulvdVeen. How do you calculate the vector CD?

Comment: Explanation too long for a comment. See https://www.vandeveen.nl/Images/Finding_C_and_D.png

Comment: I agree with your statement in general, but I must say I do believe that if all angles do turn out to be of integer degrees, there must be a "clever"(aka without calculations) way to do this. The point is that coming up with such a solution is not worth the effort, and such methods can hardly be generalized. However the problem "as is" has this neat structure that is too good to be overlooked.